# Disable JSHint warning: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript, jshint

I have the following line:

```
imageUrl && (data.imageUrl = imageUrl);
```

For this line, JSHint complains:

```
 Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
```

I understand the warning, but I want to disable it. I can’t find the way how to do it. Any idea?

Comment: It's pointlessly (imo) tricky. Why not use an if, then the warning won't happen.

Comment: @Paul Because I use this pattern a lot. I prefer to ignore this kind of error specifically for the lines I used it (not globally).

Comment: @torazaburo, no, that other question  is the other way around (jshint finding an assignment when it expected an expression)

Comment: And that other question is about jslint - and the jshint answer there isn't the best, IMO.

Comment: They don't give the `ignore:line` option. Otherwise, it's basically the same. Probably could be merged.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If it really is just that one line

```
imageUrl && (data.imageUrl = imageUrl); // jshint ignore:line
```

I am a fan of writing code so it doesn't produce warnings, though, even if this means taking special action to do so. So I'd prefer

```
if (imageUrl) data.imageUrl = imageUrl;
```

Comment: Know what? Took your advice! `if (imageURL) data.imageUrl = imageUrl` looks similar and better. Thanks!

Comment: What about `a || (a = [])`? Have any improvement for that?

Comment: `if (!a)`? `if (a.length != 0)`? Depends on what you're trying to do. Or `if (a) ; else a=[];`. Please don't do that one! (you'll get a different warning, in any case)

Comment: Thanks!
Have any idea what about: `a = (b === c)`? I get `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.`

Comment: OK, that's an odd one. I don't immediately see why it's complaining about that. On the other hand, jshint.com doesn't complain about it, so are you sure that's exactly what you used? No chance the first `=` was accidentally `==`? (which does result in your error)

Comment: And this comment chains is getting long. You should probably edit your question with all the statements/expressions you'd like to suppress warnings for

Answer (score 41):

Include a `/* jshint expr: true */` comment in your Javascript.

Reference: http://jshint.com/docs/options/#expr

Comment: That turns it off globally, and so may suppress valid warnings elsewhere, unless you put it inside the offending function