# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression in reactjs while using graphcms

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> Line 11:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an
>   expression

This is the error i get every time i run

> npm start

in my React JS app i am writing. GraphCMS for CMS. Everything is working fine, except that when I try to map posts, it gives this error.

I suspect the problem might be related to JSHint, but I have no idea how to fix this.

Here is my code:

```
import React from  'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import  { graphql} from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const LandingPage = ({data: {loading, allPosts}}) => {
    if(!loading) {
        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                {allPosts.map(post => { // <-- line 11
                    <article className="content" key={post.id}>
                        <h2>{post.title}</h2>
                        <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: post.description}}>
                            <Link to={`/post/${post.slug}`}>
                                <button className="btn">Read More</button>
                            </Link>
                        </p>
                    </article>
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
    return <h2>Loading Posts...</h2>
};

const allPosts = gql`
    query allPosts {
        allPosts {
            id
            title
            description
            slug
        }
    }
`;

export default graphql(allPosts)(LandingPage);
```

([A screen shot of the same code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3cVG.png))

Comment: Please post the complete error message and stacktrace

Comment: add return here: `return (<article className="content" key={post.id}>....</article>)` or use concise body with map callback method (replace `{}` with `()`), like this: `{allPosts.map(post => (<article ......))}`

Comment: Failed to compile
./src/LandingPage.js
  Line 11:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: @MayankShukla putting return there doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @Andreas this is all the error message i get .

Comment: @Andreas i putted down the code snapshot you can see the line 11 there. hope that helps.

Comment: @Andreas sorry for that i thought picture is not required here.

Comment: @Andreas i did try that its not working errors remains same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable JSHint warning: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623822/disable-jshint-warning-expected-an-assignment-or-function-call-and-instead-saw)

Comment: @Andreas i don't now how to ignore line in jshint. i need help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you write

```
allPosts.map(post => { <Article /> })
```

the right-hand side of the arrow function either needs to be an expression

```
allPosts.map(post => <Article />)
```

or a block containing a statement

```
allPosts.map(post => { return <Article />; })
```

The JSX `<Article />` expands to a JavaScript *expression*, which can’t be a top-level statement inside curly braces.